# How to turn off a function after a desired amount of time?

Tags: lua

I know my question would sound silly but I'm new to Lua so I'm trying to make the best practice as I can.

```lua
function wait(n)
    local start = os.time()
    repeat until os.time() > start + n
end
function hi(x)
    while x do
        print("Hi")
        wait(.5)
    end
end
hi(true)
```

For example, I want to turn off the function "hi" after running for 6 seconds and re-enable it after stopping for 2 seconds, how can I do it? Thank you so much!

Comment: os.time() returns seconds, so waiting for .5 seconds won't work.  you already know how to wait for a certain amount of time so I cannot make sense of your question.  you just have to do the same in hi as you did in wait... check the current time vs the start time and do whatever you want after the condition is true

Comment: Try ```os.clock()``` instead of ```os.time()``` than ```.5``` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this changes...

```
function wait(n)
    local start = os.clock()
    repeat until os.clock() > start + n
end
function hi(x)
    for i = 1, x do
        print("Hi")
        wait(.5)
    end
end
hi(4) -- With the hardcoded wait(.5) this will end after 2s
```

One warning.
Lua is fast so wait() will run in high performance mode.
Let it run by hi(120) for a minute will also run your fans in high cooling mode.
...it is better to have a more CPU friendly wait/sleep.

Easy Peasy with LuaJIT: https://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html

Comment: `switch = true`
`function wait(n)`
`local start = os.time()`
`repeat until os.time() > start + n`
`end`
`while switch do`
`local start1 = os.time()`
`repeat`
`print('Hi')`
`wait(.25)`
`until os.time() > start1 + 6`
`local start2 = os.time()`
`repeat`
`print("stopped")`
`wait(.75)`
`until os.time() > start2 + 2`
`end`
Seem like you don't really understand what I'm asking but thankfully I've understand how os.time() work and this code work perfectly fine. By the way thanks!